# Error inserting data into big object

Tags: big-object

Refer to pictures. I am trying to insert data into a big object and get the following error

"variable does not exist" and it refers to the textbody

[image]

[image]

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you check your permissions on TEXTBODY__C field?

Comment: What variable does it say does not exist? Surely it tells you the name?

Comment: @AdrianLarson - seems its the `TEXTBODY__c` -- *"variable does not exist" and it refers to the textbody* .. don't really see a reason why it would not work.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to include the error message verbatim.

Comment: as an aside, if this BigObject is meant to be a single emailmessage, then the API name should be `Email_Message__b`

Comment: The answer is this, I did not have the permission set for this. Make sure to have it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is this, I did not have the permission set for this. Make sure to have it. When you configure a big object, you also configure the permission set for it. When you configure a permission set for it, it is inserted into the database. You must then find it by the name you gave it an assign it to yourself, once you do that you can edit and insert data.

Comment: This answer was flagged by the system because it's a bit on the short side. Can you go into more detail here so that others with the same problem can learn from this? Which permission set did you need? Is there a link you can provide to official documentation? You can add these details by making an [edit] to your answer.

Comment: is that better?